# Liquibase - Error : relation "databasechangelog" already exists

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to integrate liquibase with our application. I'm executing it using Maven integration approach.

When I execute, I  see that creation  script for databasechangelog invoked twice and get "Table already exist" error. Below are the statements from console. I'm using liquibase-core-3.1.1 jar.

```
INFO 2014-04-28 06:49:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 2014-04-28 06:49:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: databasechangelog
INFO 2014-04-28 06:49:liquibase: ChangeSet src/main/resources/sql/postGre/db.changelog-2.0.xml::1::fms ran successfully in 555ms
INFO 2014-04-28 06:49:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: databasechangelog
SEVERE 2014-04-28 06:49:liquibase: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOG PRIMARY KEY (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME))
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" already exists
```

POM file entry

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/sql/postGre/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <defaultschemaName><<my application schema>> </defaultschemaName>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:<<mydburl>> </url>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>pwd</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

please do let me where I'm going wrong..

Comment: Can you try with liquibase-maven-plugin in version 3.1.1?

Comment: Tried, it didn't help

Comment: Your example with defaultSchemaName has a space after your placeholder. Is that space actually there? Can you try it without the defaultSchemaName?

Comment: I had tried initially without defaultSchemaName and while I was looking for solution I found a blog where they had set the defaultSchemaName and got it working, looks like it didnt help me...Regarding space...nope, there isn't space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working, we were using older version of posgres, with 9.1 version its accepting defaultSchemaName and its workign now. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: I set <defaultSchemaName> in the liquibase-maven-plugin xml, and it is now working.

Comment: I added the database name to the URL and commented out the <defaultSchemaName> section.

Answer (score 9):

for h2 database ı was have the same problem.

my connection string was

> jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;

After I removed  **DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false** from the end it starts working.

last connection string as follows:

> jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;

Comment: Most probably default value of DATABASE_TO_UPPER field is true.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add **CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;** param to your url connection. Example :

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue in Mysql database, got resolved after adding the schema name in changelog as below.

```
<changeSet author="chiran" id="Creation of Static Marker">
    <createTable tableName="STATIC_MARKER2" schemaName="SWIFT">
    <column name="marker_id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="marker_name" type="varchar(50)">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="refillable" type="BIGINT"></column>
    <column name="created" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

And below is the snapshot of maven-liquibase plugin version used.
<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
<artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.2</version>
```